# Handling Orientation in Android

Tags: android, tabs, arraylist, orientation

How can I save the state of my tabs when the device `Orientation` is changed?
I have an `ArrayList` that holds all the currently open tabs

```
ArrayList<TabHost.TabSpec> mTabList = new ArrayList<TabHost.TabSpec>();
```

Changing the `Orientation` of the device clears all the tabs the user created.

I would do it with `savedInstanceState` but I don't know how to bundle it, if that's even possible.

What are your suggestions?

Comment: you can skip the recreation of activity when the configuration changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the manifest for your activity that contains the list in question add [configChanges](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) attribute to it. For the value of the attribute set it to "orientation". This should stop the default behavior of restarting the activity which is why your list is getting cleared.

Comment: ok... I added that, its calling onConfigurationChanged but its still calling onCreate also... o_O so the tabs are still getting reset...

Comment: being that it extends TabActivity wouldnt affect it... would it? -edit- it also isnt calling onConfigurationChanged when switching to landscape mode - only portrait. I must be doing something wrong....

Comment: Hmm I'm getting this each time I change orientation... 11-22 22:00:55.503: W/PhoneWindow(1051): Previously focused view reported id 2131230728 during save, but can't be found during restore.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Buddy just put in the manifest file

```
<activity android:name="YourActivityName" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
```

Just keep in mind

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

if the above solution isn't work for you in your case then you can use

[Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)

Hope this will work...

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to save the state of the application on orientation without stopping the default behaviour on orientation changed,refer this [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)

you can use savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList(key, value)..The whole idea would depend on whether you want to load the resoures again on orientation change say if your using different layout resources for landscape and portrait modes .otherwise handling using android:configChanges="orientation" would be better choice

Comment: I would do that but there is no "savedStateInstance.putArrayList<TabHost.TabSpec>"

Comment: try using savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList(key, value).